# android ListView child animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, gallery

I build a Listview, each item of this Listview in a layout composed of a Gallery.
On click of an item of the Gallery, I want to translate it to the top of my screen.

Even with setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP); my gallery cell doesn't move outside the gallery.

I assume it's because it can't go outside it's parent view.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume it's because it can't go outside it's parent view.

you are right.

There is no way that you can move that exact view. What you can do is make yourself a new ImageView and add it to your top level layout right over the top of the selected cell. Set its image by calling .getDrawingCache() on the gallery cell. Then you can animate your new ImageView to where ever you want.

Depending on what you want to do with it once it has been moved this might work out for you. But fair warning it is a somewhat convoluted process to achieve the effect you're after